# How do I get a "Github bare" repo with wget

Tags: windows, git, github, version-control, git-bare

If I clone a Github Repository , I do normally a `git clone https://github.com/:username/:repo_name.git`. But now I've wanted to download the **bare**-Repo with `wget`but it only returns the webpage.
How can I download a git repo with http? I thought this is git over http that indeed is only a git repo served over http. But what's wrong with this request. I thought the git client do the same. Even fetch the repo with GET.

I'm grateful for any answer!

Answer (score 2):

You could do `git clone --bare` to clone the repository as a bare repository

Answer (score -1):

You can get an archive (meaning not the full history) with

```
wget https://github.com/username/reponame/tarball/master
```

This is part of the [GitHub Content API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#get-archive-link):

```
GET /repos/:owner/:repo/:archive_format/:ref
```

with:

> - `archive_format` string: Can be either tarball or zipball.
>     Default: `tarball`
> - `ref` string: A valid Git reference.
>     Default: the repository’s default branch (usually `master`)

Comment: I want to fetch the repository on the way as it does git. If it communicate over http, I think I can also use wget to achieve that.

Comment: @Sebi2020 no, you can get an archive, meaning one specific version, not the full history. For the full history... a `git clone https://...` is still the best way.

Comment: So the webserver doesn't offer some way to download the entire git directory?

Comment: @Sebi2020 no, for now, this is a download service only (nodeload: https://github.com/blog/678-meet-nodeload-the-new-download-server), not a full repo bundle.